# Проблемы с доступом к сайту на MODx после авторизации

Tags: авторизация, modx

Настраиваю Hybridauth:

1. наверное не относящееся к самой программе — не актуальное описание настройки соцсетей. Тут скорее у соцсетей постоянно что-то меняется
2. в описании к сниппету написано про контексты. Собственно это вся информация по контекстам, которую удалось найти. Кто-нибудь может подсказать как настроить работу для разных контекстов?

Пытался залогиниться через vk — появилась белая страница. Весь лог в

```
[2016-01-16 22:09:23] (ERROR @ /index.php) [HybridAuth] Oophs. Error!Потом он сжалился надо мной и начал выводить

Array
(
    [0] => 42000
    [1] => 1064
    [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `modAccess` WHERE `modAccess`.`principal` = 4' at line 1
)

[2016-01-17 00:55:57] (ERROR @ /connectors/index.php) Could not get table class for class: modAccess
[2016-01-17 00:55:57] (ERROR @ /connectors/index.php) Could not get table name for class: modAccess
[2016-01-17 00:55:57] (ERROR @ /connectors/index.php) Error 42000 executing statement: Снес совсем сниппет, весь лог в:

«Path specified for package hybridauth is not a valid or accessible directory: /home/loshopop/xxxx.xx/docs/core/components/hybridauth/model/»
```

Он забивает лог своими ошибками. Как избавиться?

Как решить проблему с контектстами и белой страницей?

UPD: снова установил hybridauth — залогинился через twitter — тоже белый экран. Лечится только завершением всех сеансов. Ошибок на этот раз в логах никаких

UPD2: теперь я окончательно запутался. установил loginza. при входе через нее тоже показывается белый экран при переходе в каталоги, причем ресурсы открываются нормально. Иногда возникает ошибка со входом в контекст web, совершенно не хочет входить в другие контексты — ошибки не показывает

Вызов

```
[[!Loginza?
&groups=`Users`
&loginContext=`web`
&addContexts=`kg,en`
]]
```

Иногда не срабатывают одни категории, иногда другие, иногда вообще никакие. Проблему найти не получается. Думал проблемы с настройками безопасности, т.к. недавно делал настройки для менеджера, но менеджер и user в разных группах.

UPD3 ну и кульминация — с телефона не заходит в большинство категорий — белый экран, когда с компьютера (незалогиненный) открывается. Теперь уже думаю, что не с ними проблема.

Comment: Белый экран - это значит 500 ошибка сервера - значит надо смотреть логи апача и выкладывать ошибки сюда. Некромантов и экстрасенсов нынче на телевидение забрали, так что ждем логов.